# How can i print the compilation options on making several C files using GCC and make

Tags: makefile

I want to print my whole file compilation options on make in my console on build.
For example on compiling  test1.c test2.c test3.c using make

should print like

```
cc -g -O1 -Wall test1.c

cc -g -O1 -Wall test2.c

cc -g -O1 -Wall test3.c
```

Comment: GNU make does that by default.

Comment: But here in my make option it is hidden ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`make -n` will show the commands make would execute without running them. Is that what you mean?

Comment: no , i want to get my whole compilation options on my source build exactly i give above

Answer (score 0):

Use `make -B -n` to see all the build commands without actually building anything.

Comment: no , i want to get my whole compilation options on my source build exactly i give above

Comment: @Renjith - in that case your question really doesn't make much sense - please try to explain what is it exactly that you are trying to do

Comment: hi Paul , i am having one project tree , having build and src are in separate directories. I have given my compilation options in my make files. But on building, the build console is just printing the file name with cc only . I just want to confirm whether my all build options are really come into build on src files (exactly my optimization option.)

Comment: It sounds like you have a bug in your makefile then - you should normally see all the options being passed to cc without doing anything special, both when you do a normal `make` or if you use my suggestion of `make -B -n` above. You should post your makefile and then people here can help you to fix it.

Comment: Oh Ok.. It is a make tree.. lot of make files. 
How can i export all of them here?

Comment: Go to the lowest makefile and run that by itself. If it fails, show it to us. If not, move up one level and repeat.